# The Google Fonts Package in Flutter app is not working

Tags: flutter, fonts, package

First, I added the google_fonts package to your pubspec dependencies.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_fonts: ^0.2.0
```

Then

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
```

and apply to a Text widget

```
        Text(
          'This is Google Fonts',
          style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 40),
        ),
        Text(
          'This is Google Fonts',
          style: GoogleFonts.adventPro(fontSize: 40),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: Restart the app

Comment: Have you closed and rebuilt the app after installing the Google Fonts package?

Comment: Yes, I have already close project and IDE but i have not tried flutter clean command :) I hope this one works. Thank you so much Benjamin and João Soares.

Comment: I've tried flutter clean also but not working

Answer (score 9):

Please check internet connection- your emulator does not have internet connectivity. google fonts need internet connection on device/emulator.

Comment: Jesus! Days looking for this simple solution!

Comment: I have the same problem. I am connected to the internet, but Google fonts is blocked in my country.

Answer (score 3):

`Google Fonts` are fetched from the internet in the runtime. So you observe this behaviour

To overcome this, download the font from `google font` and make it available in the `asset folder` by following the steps below.

1. Visit the https://fonts.google.com/ and download the `lato` font.
2. At the root directory, create a directory called `google_fonts`.
3. Copy-Paste `lato.ttf` file into the `google_fonts` folder.
4. Open the `pubspec.yaml` file, Under the assets: section add the `-google_fonts/`

And change the code from

```
// Online Mode
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font'
  style: GoogleFonts.lato(),
),
```

to

```
// Offline Mode
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font',
   style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'lato') // This is loaded from assets
),
```

For futher reference refer [this](https://www.flutterbeads.com/google-fonts-in-flutter/) article.

Refer these stackoverflow answers aswell:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74949875/13431819
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74950261/13431819

Comment: This is a hack, please use @Agita's answer below

Answer (score 1):

After adding the dependency pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_fonts: ^0.2.0
```

run the command in terminal\cmd console as :

```
> flutter packages get
```

this will fetch the dependency into your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you [store the fonts in your assets](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts#bundling-font-files-in-your-applications-assets), you need to define **explicitly** that runtime fetching is enabled for Google Fonts:

`GoogleFonts.config.allowRuntimeFetching = true;`

Alternatively, you can disallow fetching fonts at runtime with

`GoogleFonts.config.allowRuntimeFetching = false;`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by deleting the emulator and installing a new one. My older emulator was not connecting to the internet for some reason and reinstalling it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Google Fonts in offline mode:

```
Visit the https://fonts.google.com/ and download the required fonts.
At the root directory, create a directory called google_fonts.
Copy-Paste [font].ttf file into the google_fonts folder.
Open the pubspec.yaml file, Under the assets: section add the -google_fonts/
```

NOTE: Make sure you don’t change the name of the font file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator or simulator, then it probably may not be an issue of internet connection. It's only when you are using a physical device.
**In the case of an emulator**, it's just an IDE glitch. **Invalidate cache** in Android Studio or IntelliJ and you are good to go.