# Does google font package download the fonts on the device?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fonts

In my flutter Android app, on first launch, the app shows a default font and then a second later it changes to the fonts I used from google fonts flutter package. I guess my question is, does the font download as soon as the app launches for the first time ?, if so can the font be compiled with the app so it doesn't require to be downloaded on the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) is fetching them over HTTP at runtime. It's really good for development purposes, but when you choose which font you want to stick with, do as they recommend, which is to download the font and put it on the assets folder, this way, the package won't download anything, rather take it from you assets folder.

For more info: [read this](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts#bundling-font-files-in-your-applications-assets).

> The google_fonts package will automatically use matching font files in
> your pubspec.yaml's assets (rather than fetching them at runtime via
> HTTP). Once you've settled on the fonts you want to use:
>
> Download the font files from https://fonts.google.com. You only need
> to download the weights and styles you are using for any given family.
> Move those fonts to a top-level app
> directory (e.g. google_fonts).
>
> Ensure that you have listed the folder (e.g. google_fonts/) in your
> pubspec.yaml under assets.
>
> Note: Since these files are listed as assets, there is no need to list
> them in the fonts section of the pubspec.yaml. This can be done
> because the files are consistently named from the Google Fonts API (so
> be sure not to rename them!)

Comment: I would say put Google fonts under assets: `assets/google_fonts`

Answer (score 4):

`Google Fonts` are fetched from the internet in the runtime. So you observe this behaviour

To overcome this, download the font from `google font` and make it available in the `asset folder` and change the code from

```
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font'
  style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(),
),
```

to

```
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font',
   style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'hammersmithOne') // This is loaded from assets
),
```

For futher reference refer [this](https://www.flutterbeads.com/google-fonts-in-flutter/) article.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, but you should keep in mind that if your device does not have the ability to connect to Wi-Fi or a mobile network as app is launched, then the fonts from this package will not be downloaded to the device and flutter will apply its default font.