# how to add google fonts

Tags: flutter, dart, google-font-api

```
child: RichText(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        text: const TextSpan(
                            text: "What are you looking for?", //here
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black87,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
```

help me to insert google font on the text section. This is the code style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add dependency in your pubspec.yaml [google_fonts: ^3.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts)

then use style property in your text widget

```
Text('What are you looking for?',
style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(
  fontSize: 48,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
  color: Colors.greenAccent),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `Google Fonts` two ways , when `online` and `offline`

[image]

### Online

1. Download package [`google_fonts`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts), it fetches `google fonts` from the internet.
2. add import statement `import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart'`
3. Use it in the style

   ```
   Text(
     'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font'
     style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(),
   ),
   ```

### Offline

1. Visit the https://fonts.google.com/ and download the `hammersmithOne` font.
2. At the root directory, create a directory called `google_fonts`.
3. Copy-Paste `hammersmithOne.ttf` file into the `google_fonts` folder.
4. Open the `pubspec.yaml` file, Under the assets: section add the `-google_fonts/`

   ```
   Text(
     'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font',
      style: GoogleFonts.getFont('hammersmithOne'),
      // style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'hammersmithOne') <-- This can also be used.
   ),
   ```

#### Note: Changing Google Font at App Level

If you want the font to change throughtout the app use the following code:

```
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(
      Theme.of(context).textTheme,
    ),
   // fontFamily:'hammersmithOne' <-- this can also be used
  ),
  home: GoogleFontDemo(),
);
```

Comment: CategoriesWidget(
              text: "Frozen Food", 
              style: "GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne()", //here
              icon: "images/frozen.png",
              press: () => {

Comment: how to style the googleFonts on this way?

Comment: i got it already thenks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the font in the `style` property of the `Text` widget.

Example:

```html
child: RichText(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        text: const TextSpan(
                            text: "What are you looking for?", //here
                            style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(
                             textStyle : TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black87,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              )
                            ),
```