# I see different font familiy when i upload to google play store

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, google-fonts

I use google_fonts in my flutter project. while i run the code, i can see my font settings in the app. but, when i upload my app to google play console, i cant see my font familiy settings, i see different font family. what is the problem?

```
static TextStyle styleGraphicBoldText = GoogleFonts.mali(
  color: MainColor.mainColor,
  fontSize: (AppConfig.screenHeight!) / 70,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
);
```

```
home: HomePage(
  prefs: prefs,
),
theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.maliTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)),
```

I tried to run `flutter clean`, changing version name. They didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Google fonts` uses internet, so you may have to update the dependencies in the `manifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Else you can try to make the `google font` available in the `offline` by adding it in the assets folder.

```
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  //  textTheme: GoogleFonts.maliTextTheme(
  //    Theme.of(context).textTheme,
  //  ),
   fontFamily:'maliTextTheme' <--  Use this code to load offline
  ),
  home: GoogleFontDemo(),
);
```

Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74949875/13431819

Comment: thanks, permission solved problem.